# bootstrap css not working in chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

In joomla i create a page. 
I create a responsive fixed position categories menus below banner.

Desktop-view

[image]

I create a sticky button for.
Mobile view
[image]

On drop-down menu category display. 
In chrome i check mobile view layout on monitor, 
this work, but in my mobile check in chrome, 
menus not work. 
I update a version of chrome in mobile they work.
I want this work on old version of chrome...how to solve this.
Please help

Comment: Please provide code example or link. It's nearly impossible to help you this way.

Answer (score 0):

**Basically, to do the backward compatibility is difficult**. 
One option is to use common components that can be compatible with both older and new versions.

Otherwise, you may need to accept the difference between different browsers as a condition.

The following reference provides necessary information to create Cross-Browser apps. This may help you.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/

Regards.